# Odds ratios from logistic regression on subsets of data using R

Tags: r, logistic, repeated-measures

I have 15 subjects each with 200 trials & I'd like to run separate regressions for each subject.

If I just run the regression on the whole dataset I am able to generate odds ratios / confidence intervals from it:

```
acc.log = glm(response ~ phdot + sdot, data=fullerr, family="binomial")
summary(acc.log)

exp(acc.log$coefficients)
exp(confint(acc.log))
```

But then when I fit each subject separately (I've tried using `by`), I am an unsure how to then extract information like odds ratios (standard errors & p values are also no longer shown in the output).

```
split.acc <- by(fullerr, fullerr[,"subject"], function(fullerr){ 
                  glm(response ~ phdot + sdot, data=fullerr, family="binomial")
                })
```